# Multiple iterations of sanity check whilst using getchar(), how do I avoid?

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm currently making a projectile motion calculator. Nothing super complicated, however i'm using a sanity check as below:

```
printf("Please enter initial velocity: ");
while (!scanf("%lg", &velocity)|| velocity<0){
     getchar();
     printf("Velocity is not valid, enter again: ");
}
```

It works perfectly in stopping negative numbers and single characters, however when the user inputs a word with multiple characters the second printf will reiterate equal to however many characters are in the word.

How do I make it so when the user inputs a word, the sanity check still functions as it should but only runs once?

Comment: Use `fgets` and parse instead of these exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Call `getchar()` in a loop until you see a newline:

```
printf("Please enter initial velocity: ");
while (!scanf("%lg", &velocity)|| velocity<0){
     while (getchar() != '\n');
     printf("Velocity is not valid, enter again: ");
}
```

Comment: Will not terminate with file input

Comment: I'd test `scanf("%lg", &velocity) != 1` to consider EOF too.